# Gradle won't allow input via Windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, gradle, command-line

On a shell server that has the JDK installed, the following program allows input from the user by reading in the next integer and displaying the correct output:

```
package hello;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int theNextInt = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Next integer is: " + theNextInt);
  }
}
```

However, when I perform `gradlew run` on my Windows console, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
:run FAILED
```

Of course, the exception occurs because `Scanner` is not reading any more elements. **That's because the Windows console won't allow me to input.** Any way around this?

Comment: I don't know Gradle but in programming languages adding a `w` to the end of a program, as in `gradlew`, indicates a GUI program. GUI programs are programs without a console and can't access the console that started them. Use the console version of your program.

Comment: @Noodles the `w` means to run gradle without having it installed. It is short for "wrapper".

Regardless I tried running `gradle run` and I ran into the same issue.

Comment: @Mofi: There's a reason why you are allowed to edit posts.

Comment: @Mofi: The OP gets notified when you edit their post. The *Edit summary* field would then be a good place to leave your rationale. If you don't like that, you could always leave an "I edited your question, because ..." comment in addition to your edit.

Comment: @IInspectable I wouldn't mess with Mofi, it's a self-destructing comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that after doing further research, I ran into [this question](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-doesnt-system-in-read-block-when-im-using-gradle/3308) and [this question](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-execute-a-java-application-that-asks-for-user-input/3264) which offer the same solution (that works):

Include the following in the `build.gradle` file:

```
run {

standardInput = System.in

}
```

because according to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html), the InputStream defaults to empty for a task of type `JavaExec`.